# Create binary package with Rnw files in R

Tags: r

I would like to create a binary R package. The below testFun would be the final function that the user would call. Once the `testFun()` is executed in the console, I want the PDF file to be created (this is the objective). I am new to creating R Packages. Can you please help me the following example ? Thanks for your help.

Below are the 2 files i am using to create a package out of it.

R CODE:

```
testFun <- function(){

library(knitr)

#knit(input = system.file("testReport.Rnw", output = "testReport.tex"))

knit2pdf("testReport.Rnw") }
```

RNW FILE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\begin{document} some stuff \end{document}
```

Please let me know, if my question is not clear.

Comment: You should edit your question and update the function, instead of using the comments.

Comment: Sorry i tried doing it, But not sure how to do it. Thats why posted as comment.

Comment: There is an edit button under your question.